# Contradiction in the scriptures regarding the destiny of the wicked

Tags: contradiction

How do you resolve the conflict in the Scriptures between where we read that the wicked will be damned and where there are clear indications that all will be saved?

For example, the Scriptural texts below seem to indicate the final salvation of all born of Adam and Eve:

> Genesis 22:18  And in thy seed shall all the nations of the earth be blessed; because thou hast obeyed my voice.
>
> Genesis 28:14   And thy seed shall be as the dust of the earth, and thou shalt spread abroad to the west, and to the east, and to the north, and to the south: and in thee and in thy seed shall all the families of the earth be blessed.
>
> Luke 3:6   And all flesh shall see the salvation of God.
>
> Ephesians 1:10: That in the dispensation of the fulness of times he might gather together in one all things in Christ, both which are in heaven, and which are on earth; even in him:
>
> Colossians 1:20: And, having made peace through the blood of his cross, by him to reconcile all things unto himself; by him, I say, whether they be things in earth, or things in heaven.
>
> Revelation 5:13 And every creature which is in heaven, and on the earth, and under the earth, and such as are in the sea, and all that are in them, heard I saying, Blessing, and honour, and glory, and power, be unto him that sitteth upon the throne, and unto the Lamb for ever and ever.